# В asyncio не все coros выполняются до конца

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio, micropython

Начал разбираться в asyncio. Делаю тестовую программу в которой асинхронно запускаются несколько функций и которые засыпают на определенное время. Для проверки хода выполнения кода в каждой функции вывожу на печать строку начала (`">>test_2 start"`) и окончания кода (`"<<test_2 close"`). Пока все функции (coros) спят, основная функция `main()` подходит к концу и принудительно завершает цикл со всеми спящими coros. Поэтому программа выполняется не полностью, завершающие строки не выводятся на печать (`"<<test_2 close"`).

Вопрос в том , как сделать так чтобы основной цикл не заканчивался до полного завершения всех спящих coros?

Конечно, в `main()` можно прописать `await uasyncio.sleep(t)` (где t - время выполнении всех функций), чтобы функция `main()` "спала", но время выполнения coros может варьироваться, поэтому точное время указать не могу.

Моя программа работает на микроконтроллере c MicroPython, поэтому использую модуль uasyncio. Не стоит обращать на это внимание.

```
import uasyncio, utime

def test_1():
    for x in range(1,5):
        print("test_1", x)

async def test_2():
    print(">>test_2 start")
    for x in range(1,3):
        print("async test_2", x)
    await uasyncio.sleep(2)
    print("<<test_2 close")
    
async def test_3():
    print(">>test_3 start")
    await uasyncio.sleep(3)
    for x in range(1,4):
        print("test_3", x)
    print("<<test_3 close")
    

async def test_4():
    print(">>test_4 start")
    for x in range(1,4):
        print("test_4", x)
    await uasyncio.sleep(1)
    print("<<test_4 close")
        

async def main():
    t2 = uasyncio.create_task(test_2())
    t3 = uasyncio.create_task(test_3())
    t4 = uasyncio.create_task(test_4())
    await uasyncio.sleep(0)
    test_1()
    print("Test message")


try:
    loop = uasyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())

finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Каким-либо образом дожидаться завершения этих самых t2, t3 и t4 (в документации uasyncio написано, что у него тоже есть gather)

Comment: @andreymal Уже читал про gather. Он выполняет несколько coros одновременно. Но в моем эксперименте и в предполагаемом проекте между корутинами (в main()) находится обычный линейный код (print или обычная функция), который не попадет в gather. Можно конечно эти участки кода обернуть в асинхронные функции и положить в gather, если других вариантов нет.

Comment: «Обычный» код блокирует работу асинхронщины, поэтому его в каких-то значимых количествах быть в принципе не должно

Comment: await asyncio.wait([t2, t3, t4])

Comment: @ВасяПупкин у вас в вопросе нет таких проблемных кусков кода, с которыми бы не справился gather. Измените вопрос так, чтобы он демонстрировал вашу проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Раз нет `wait`, используйте `gather`:

```
try:
    import uasyncio
except ImportError:
    import asyncio as uasyncio

...        

async def main():
    t2 = uasyncio.create_task(test_2())
    t3 = uasyncio.create_task(test_3())
    t4 = uasyncio.create_task(test_4())
    await uasyncio.gather(t2, t3, t4)
    test_1()
    print("Test message")

...
```

Вывод:

```
>>test_2 start
async test_2 1
async test_2 2
>>test_3 start
>>test_4 start
test_4 1
test_4 2
test_4 3
<<test_4 close
<<test_2 close
test_3 1
test_3 2
test_3 3
<<test_3 close
test_1 1
test_1 2
test_1 3
test_1 4
Test message
```

Чтобы циклы в корутинах могли работать "параллельно" (могло происходить переключение на другую корутину в процессе выполнения циклов), должен быть `asyncio.sleep` на каждой итерации цикла (в реальных задачах это может быть `await asyncio.sleep(0)`, тогда задержка не будет добавляться, но это позволит переключаться на другие корутины):

```
async def test_2():
    print(">>test_2 start")
    for x in range(1,3):
        print("async test_2", x)
        await uasyncio.sleep(1)
    
    print("<<test_2 close")
    
async def test_3():
    print(">>test_3 start")
    
    for x in range(1,4):
        print("test_3", x)
        await uasyncio.sleep(1)

    print("<<test_3 close")
    

async def test_4():
    print(">>test_4 start")
    for x in range(1,4):
        print("test_4", x)
        await uasyncio.sleep(1)
    print("<<test_4 close")
```

Результат:

```
>>test_2 start
async test_2 1
>>test_3 start
test_3 1
>>test_4 start
test_4 1
async test_2 2
test_3 2
test_4 2
<<test_2 close
test_3 3
test_4 3
<<test_3 close
<<test_4 close
test_1 1
test_1 2
test_1 3
test_1 4
Test message
```

Comment: Хотел бы уточнить условие моей задачи. "Функция test_1 должна выполняться во время простоя test_2,3,4. При этом test_1 остается НЕасинхронной функцией". Функция test_1 может быть заменена просто одной строкой декларации переменной и печатью в порт и прочей незначительной мелочью, которую не хочется записывать отдельной функцией или добавлять в другую. 
Метод gather плох тем , что блокирует выполнение последующего кода до завершения всех coros и , соответственно, увеличивает время выполнения общего кода.

Comment: Ок, допустим. Но каким образом вариант в вашем ответе решает эту проблему? Никаким, он точно также будет блокировать выполнение последующего кода.

Comment: Чтобы test_1 мог выполняться параллельно, его можно, например, отправить в отдельный поток. Через обычный asyncio можно сделать asyncio.to_thread(), и добавить в общий список ожидаемых корутин в gather. Как на micropython - не могу сказать, не факт что там to_thread есть. Если нет, то можно попробовать запускать просто в отдельном потоке.

Comment: я внес сравнительный код в свой ответ, прошу ознакомиться. С потоками еще не работал, нужно изучить это направление.

Comment: @ВасяПупкин, собственно, см. комментарий andreymal под вашим ответом.

Answer (score -2):

Решил задачу добавлением в main() следующего кода:

```
while  (t2.done(),t3.done(),t4.done()) != (True,True,True): 
    print("{} Цикл не закончен".format(count))
    await uasyncio.sleep_ms(500)
```

Он проверяет завершены ли все задачи, если нет, то усыпляю цикл , давая возможность завершиться заданиям.

---

@insolor

> Но каким образом вариант в вашем ответе решает эту проблему?

Приведу сравнение двух вариантов. Код немного упростил ( как мне кажется) по сравнению с первоначальным вопросом. Вариант с использованием gather:

```
try:
    import uasyncio
except ImportError:
    import asyncio as uasyncio

try:
    import utime #модуль MicroPython для работы с процессорным временем
except ImportError:
    import time as utime


def do_something_small():
    utime.sleep(1) #имитация работы функцииs
    print("do")


async def coro_1():
    print(">>coro_1 start")
    await uasyncio.sleep(2) #ожидание каких либо данных
    print("<<coro_1 stop")



async def main():
    start = utime.ticks_ms()    #запускаю отсчет времени
    t1 = uasyncio.create_task(coro_1() )
    await uasyncio.gather(t1)

    do_something_small()
    print("Test message")

    end = utime.ticks_ms()     #завершаю отсчет времени
    time = utime.ticks_diff(end,start) #расчет истекшего времени
    print("Cycle time =",time,"ms")


try:
    uasyncio.run(main())
```

В результате gather выполняется первым, после чего выполняются остальные функции:

```
>>coro_1 start
<<coro_1 stop
do
Test message
Cycle time = 3026 ms
```

Далее мой вариант с созданием task и проверкой его/их завершения:

```
try:
    import uasyncio
except ImportError:
    import asyncio as uasyncio

try:
    import utime
except ImportError:
    import time as utime


def do_something_small():
    utime.sleep(1) #имитация работы функции
    print("do")


async def coro_1():
    print(">>coro_1 start")
    await uasyncio.sleep(2) #ожидание каких либо данных
    print("<<coro_1 stop")


async def main():
    start_timer = utime.ticks_ms()

    t1 = uasyncio.create_task(coro_1() )

    await uasyncio.sleep(0)
    
    do_something_small() #делаю что-либо во время простоя coro_1
    print("Test message")#печатаю что-либо во время простоя coro_1
    
    while not t1.done():# жду завершения coro_1
        await uasyncio.sleep_ms(100)
    
    end_timer = utime.ticks_ms()
    time = utime.ticks_diff(end_timer,start_timer)
    print("Cycle time =",time,"ms")


try:
    uasyncio.run(main())
```

Результат:

```
>>coro_1 start
do
Test message
<<coro_1 stop
Cycle time = 2006 ms
```

Как видно время выполнения уменьшилось, за счет использования времени простоя. Поскольку функция main() является асинхронной, то во время простоя coro_1 выполняется всё остальное содержимое main.
Это вариант, конечно , не идеальный, но для каких-нибудь нужд пригодится.

Comment: Ну и дичь) есть же asincio.gather и asyncio.wait

Comment: while  not all(t2.done(),t3.done(),t4.done()):

Comment: @eri "Это дичь? Дичь! А под дичь водку не пьют. Еще по 150 шампанского и ВСЁ..."
Вы абсолютно правы в своих утверждениях. Чем мне не удобен gather я объяснил чуть выше. А вот asyncio.wait() в MicroPython отcутствует, поэтому о его существовании даже не знал, пытаясь внедрить этот метод в программу получал ошибку. Прочитал документацию по Python asyncio.wait() нашел это решением действительно интересным, жаль не для моего случая. Тем не менее спасибо, буду дальше экспериментировать  и адаптировать эти методы под свои нужды.

Comment: @СергейШ спасибо за такую ценную поправку. Век живи, век учись .

Comment: @ВасяПупкин всё ещё непонятно чем вам gather не угодил

Comment: Показанные вами два варианта не эквивалентны друг другу по логике работы. Чтобы они стали эквивалентными, в первом варианте переместите gather ПОСЛЕ вызова do_something_small

Comment: @andreymal Не вижу никакой разницы от перестановки. И gather и do_something_small являются функциями блокирующими процессор, конечный результат (время выполнения) не зависит от их пложения в программе. На всякий случай уточню, что именно utime.sleep(1)  блокирует процессор на 1 секунду.

Comment: @ВасяПупкин а хотя есть ещё одна неэквивалентность — во втором варианте вы поставили `await uasyncio.sleep(0)` перед do_something_small, а в первом варианте не поставили. Если тоже поставите (и переставите gather), то первый вариант тоже будет занимать две секунды

Comment: В общем, во втором варианте достаточно просто заменить while на gather, и получится то что надо

Comment: @andreymal Да, ваш вариант работает. Такой способ использования gather мне кажется не очень "кашерным", потому что мы его используем не для запуска очереди заданий , а для проверки их завершения. Он короче моего варианта - да, понятнее/очевиднее - нет. В документации такого не найдешь. Раз этот вариант работает то и ладно. Спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: @ВасяПупкин запуском занимается create_task (и await uasyncio.sleep нужен для того, чтобы он передал управление в event loop, чтобы у того появилась возможность начать фактическое выполнение таски и запустить двухсекундное ожидание)

Comment: @andreymal Это понятно. Но читаю документацию Python asyncio. Там приводится такой код запуска для gather: 
```# Schedule three calls *concurrently*:
    L = await asyncio.gather(
        factorial("A", 2),
        factorial("B", 3),
        factorial("C", 4),
    )
```
в чем разница ?

Comment: @ВасяПупкин ни в чём. В той же самой документации чуток выше написано, что если в gather передаются не таски, то они будут созданы автоматически (если полистать исходный код функции gather, то там видно, что в какой-то момент вызывается тот же самый create_task)